# Access elements in a custom view component in Swift 3 UI testing

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, swift3, xcode-ui-testing

I'm a newbie to any type of iOS programming. I am trying to write UI test cases for one of my scenes.

Following is the code I'm getting when I use recode method and tap on the custom component.

```
let button = XCUIApplication().children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .button).element
```

In this custom component there are two buttons. I wanna know which button is selected. For that I need to identify the button. But i'm getting same code where ever I tap on the custom view.

How can I access each component inside custom view. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 10):

Add an accessibility identifier to your custom view in the app's code.

```
let customView: UIView!
customView.accessibilityIdentifier = "myCustomView"
```

Then access the contents like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let customView = app.otherElements["myCustomView"]
let button1 = customView.buttons.element(boundBy: 0)
let button2 = customView.buttons.element(boundBy: 1)
XCTAssertTrue(button1.isSelected)
XCTAssertFalse(button2.isSelected)
```

Note that to make your test deterministic, you should already know which button(s) should be selected. This ensures that your test tests the same thing every time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make you elements visible to Accessibility.

I would suggest you to watch the [WWDC Session about UI Testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/) especially [this part](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/?time=2382)